# Laravel-mix custom rules not working?

Tags: laravel, reactjs, laravel-5, webpack

I am trying to use [this package](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#modules) to use my scss as javascript objects in my React part of my Laravel project.

Now when I try do add the rule to my `webpack.mix.js` folder I always get the following error for all my .scss files

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-5!./node_modules/css-loader??ref--9-0!./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
Module build failed: 

^
      Invalid CSS after "e": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "exports = module.ex"
      in /Users/user/Desktop/project/resources/assets/sass/app.scss (line 1, column 1)
 @ ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss 2:14-318
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
```

my webpack.mix.js file:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            modules: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

### EDIT

I've updated my webpack.mix.js and added the sass-loader but same error

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            modules: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            modules: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: you need sass-loader too

Comment: @MatheusSilva I have the sass-loader installed and added the rule but same error (check edited op)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a very nice npm package that fixed all my issues:

https://github.com/leinelissen/laravel-mix-react-css-modules

Answer (score -1):

There is no modules option to `sass-loader`. Also install style-loader

Try:

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            modules: true
                        }
                    },
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: See my answer I found a very nice package that fixed all my issues with very little setup